# Deploy .sh file in ec2 using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, devops

i am trying to deploy *.sh file located in my localhost to ec2,using terraform.Note that all infrastructure i am creating via terraform.So for copy file to the remote host i am using terraform provisioner.The question is,how i can find out a private_key or password for ubuntu-user for deploying.Or maybe somebody knows different solution.The goal to run .sh file in ec2.Thanks before hand)

Comment: resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
...
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "~/foobar"
    destination = "~/foobar"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("~/Downloads/AWS_keys/test.pem")}"
      host        = "${self.public_dns}"
    }
  }
...
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using a provisioner and you have the private key local to where Terraform is being executed, then SCSI-9's solution should work well.

However, if you can't ensure the private key is available then you could always do something like how Elastic Beanstalk deploys and use S3 as an intermediary.

Something like this.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "script" {
  bucket = module.s3_bucket.bucket_name
  key = regex("([^/]+$)", var.script_file)[0]
  source = var.script_file
  etag = filemd5(var.script_file)
}

resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_object.script]
  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/.scripts/userdata.sh" {
    s3_bucket = module.s3_bucket.bucket_name
    object_key = aws_s3_bucket_object.script.id
  }
  ...
}
```

And then somewhere in your userdata script, you can fetch the object from s3.

```sh
aws s3 cp s3://${s3_bucket}/${object_key} /some/path
```

Of course, you will also have to ensure that the instance has permissions to read from the s3 bucket, which you can do by attaching a role to the EC2 instance with the appropriate policy.